# CSS webkit animations 'stacking' with multiple elements

Tags: html, css, webkit

I've been trying to do a looping scrolling animation for some comments using webkit, however whenever I apply the animation the effects seem to 'stack' up, and each element of the comment class will be slightly faster than the animation before. Here is my code:

CSS

```
.comment {
content:'';
-webkit-animation: movecomments 18s linear infinite;
-moz-animation: movecomments 18s linear infinite;
-o-animation: movecomments 18s linear infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes movecomments {
    0% {margin-top: 500px;}
    100% {margin-top: 0px;}
}
@-moz-keyframes movecomments {
    0% {margin-top: 500px;}
    100% {margin-top: 0px;}
}
@-o-keyframes movecomments {
    0% {margin-top: 500px;}
    100% {margin-top: 0px;}
```

HTML (Roughly goes like this, the actual comments are echoed with PHP)

```
<div class="comment">1</div>
<div class="comment">2</div>
<div class="comment">3</div>
<div class="comment">4</div>
```

You can check an example of it at [my website](http://woopville.uphero.com), at the bottom of the page in the comment section.